# Displaying the content of a vector

Tags: c++

```
string s="dog cat cat dog"
vector<string>v;
for(int i=0;i<s.length();)
{
    string str;
    while(s[i]!=' ')
    {
        str.push_back(s[i]);
            i++;
    }
    v.push_back(str);
    i++;
}
for(auto it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
{
    cout<<*(it)<<" ";
}
```

I want my output to be like:

```
dog cat cat dog
```

But I am getting some unwanted symbols also in the output and don't know what they mean.

Output:

```
dog cat cat dog ♫)±*→╒ ‼♥       ♦               dog             ♫)≡+→╒  ►\☻     P☺☻             dog ♫)±*        ♫)±*→╒ ‼♥       ♦               cat             ♫)±*→╒ ‼♥       ♦               cat             ▬)≡3→╒  ≡^☻     Ç[☻             dog ♫)±*→╒ ‼♥    ☺ 8→╒  P☺☻     ♣ ☺♦↔╒ ↨
```

What are these?

Answer (score 1):

Your original string s, does not end with a `' '` character. This means that your while loop does not terminate at the end of s. You can prevent this by checking i against the length of s.

```
while(s[i]!=' ' and i < s.length())
```

Comment: The `length` check should be first, `while (i < s.length() && s[i] != ' ')`, otherwise `s[i]` will access the null terminator after the last iteration (which is undefined behavior prior to C++11, but is legal in C++11 onward).

Comment: Good point. It was my understanding that strings in C and C++ always end with the null character. I learned

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70793384/65863) already explained the problem with your code.

A much simpler way to split the string on spaces is to use `std::istringstream` with `operator>>`, eg:

```cpp
string s = "dog cat cat dog", str;
vector<string> v;
istringstream iss(s);
while (iss >> str)
{
    v.push_back(str);
}
for(const auto &str_in_v : v)
{
    cout << str_in_v << " ";
}
```